# Add intellisense documentation to StructureMap

Tags: intellisense, structuremap

By default all I get in intellisense are the functions and its signature. I would prefer if I could also get documentation with the intellisense. I realise that I am supposed to place an xml file that contains this documentation along with my dll.

From where can I get this is file? Or is there some other way for me to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the immediate future, there's no way to get the XML documentation short of grabbing the Structuremap source and building it yourself.

As for why that's not included with the distribution, I'm not sure. My only guess is that back when xml-based configuration with SM was more prevalent, Jeremy was concerned about confusion between StructureMap.xml the intellisense file, and StructureMap.xml the configuration file.

That's pure speculation however. For the real scoop you'd have to post on the SM-mailing list. Regardless, for the time being, you have to roll your own from the source. I've done this as well for the same reason, and it wasn't too painful.

-Scott

**Edit - Instructions for doing this follow.**

1. Using your favorite SVN client (if you don't have one, I recommend [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/)) grab the latest from https://structuremap.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/structuremap/trunk/ . If you want the same bits that are in 2.5.3, I *think* you'll want revision 234. Otherwise, just grab the head and build from that. (If you aren't familiar with SVN, find a tutorial that explains what I'm talking about)
2. Open up the StructureMap solution in Visual Studio (under the Source subdirectory). Right click the StructureMap project, Go to Properties > Build and ensure the option for XML output documentation is checked.
3. Build and enjoy.

Comment: Can you please link to the tools that you used for the same? And if possible maybe a short description of what you did. Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded the source from the following url. The revision number is 232 :)

https://structuremap.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/structuremap/branches/2.5.3

Followed your steps and now I have meaningful intellisense. Thanks!